# $A$ closed, $B$ compact, both non-empty - counterexample in R to show that $d(A,B)$ NOT = $d(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Defining $d(A,B) = \inf d(a,b)$ for $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, give a counterexample to show that there does NOT exist $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ so that $d(A,B) = d(a,b)$. I can think of $X = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ where $B = [-10,-1]$ and $A = (0,10]$ but cannot think of something in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you use the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, the only counterexamples are where at least one of $A$ and $B$ is empty. That is because in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric, closed "balls" of finite radius are compact.

Comment: Your example works in $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly $d(a,b)=1$, but for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, $d(a,b)>1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've edited it to say two non-empty sets. Would this mean there are such points a and b so that $d(a,b)$=$d(A,B)$? Is there any such proof?

Comment: @Aweygan If this example is taken on R and not R\{0} then B would have to be [0,10] - then not sure why $d(a,b)$ > 1? I'd have thought it'd be |-1-0| = 1 = $d(A,B)$.

Comment: @FarmanH Ahh I forgot the requirements that $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ are closed,non-empty, and $B$ is compact : For $n\in \mathbb N, $ take $a_n\in A$ and $b_n\in B$ such that $$d(A,B)\leq |a_n-b_n|<d(A,B)+1/n.$$ Since $B$ is compact, take  a strictly increasing $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}b_{f(n)}= b\in B.$$ For clarity of notation let $b_{f(n)}=b'_n$ and $a_{f(n)}=a'_n.$ We have $\lim_{n\to \infty}|a'_n-b'_n|=d(A,B).$

For all but finitely many $n$ we have $|a'_n-b'_n|<d(A,B)+1.$ And for all but finitely many $n$ we have |$b'_n-b|<1.$ So $(a'_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a bounded sequence.

So take a strictly increasing $g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a'_{g(n)}=a.$ Since $A$ is closed we have $a\in A.$   Now we have $$d(A,B)\leq |a-b|\leq |a-a'_{g(n)}|+|a'_{g(n)}-b'_{g(n)}|+|b'_{g(n)}-b|.$$ The  RHS above  converges to $d(A,B)$ as $n\to \infty.$ $$ \text {So } d(A,B)=|a-b|.$$

Remark: If it it not obvious to you that $(a'_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence: Take $n_0$ such that $n>n_0\implies |a'_n-b'_n|<d(A,B)+1$ and take $n_1$ such that $n>n_1\implies |b'_n-b|<1.$ Let $n_2=\max (n_0,n_1).$ Then $$n>n_2\implies  |a'_n|\leq |a'_n-b'_n|+|b'_n-b|+|b|<(d(A,B)+1)+1+b=K.$$ So for all $n$ we have $|a'_n|\leq \max (K, \max \{|a'_j|:j\leq n_2\}).$